# how can i store floor plan dynamically?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a college project to create floor plan designing software.. For that I am trying  to create floorplan with help of HTML Canvas and grids. I want to save the interactive floor plan created into database but not able to as when floor plan is saved in database, it is converted to image file.. I want to know how to save an interactive map in database after creation of map and also fetch it to do alteration.

The code of simple canvas map is as follows..

```
 <!doctype>
 <html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body style=" background: lightblue;">
 <canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px"style="background: #fff; magrin:20px;"> 
 Browser does not support canvas </canvas>
 <img id="canvasImg" alt="Right click to save me!">
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">                                                                                  
 var bw = 400;
 var bh = 400;
 var p = 10;
 var cw = bw + (p*2) + 1;
 var ch = bh + (p*2) + 1;

 var grid = 50;

 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

 function drawBoard(){

 context.beginPath();
 for (var x = 0; x <= bw; x += grid){
 context.moveTo(0.5 + x + p, p);
 context.lineTo(0.5 + x + p, bh + p);
 }
 for (var x = 0; x <= bh; x += grid) {
 context.moveTo(p, 0.5 + x + p);
 context.lineTo(bw + p, 0.5 + x + p);
 }
 context.lineWidth = 1;
 context.strokeStyle = "black";
 context.stroke();

 }
 drawBoard();

 function drawRect() {

 context.beginPath();
 context.rect(0.5+p+5*grid, 0.5+p+3*grid, 2*grid, 3*grid);
 context.rect(0.0+p+0*grid, 0.0+p+0*grid, 0*grid, 0*grid);
 context.rect(0.5+p+3*grid, 0.5+p+3*grid, 2*grid, 3*grid);
 context.rect(0.5+p+0*grid, 0.5+p+0*grid, 2*grid, 3*grid);
 context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
 context.fill();
 context.lineWidth = 2;
 context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
 context.stroke();
 }
 drawRect();

  ////new 

 var el = document.getElementById('canvas');
 var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
 var isDrawing;

 el.onmousedown = function(e) {
 isDrawing = true;
 ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
 };
 el.onmousemove = function(e) {
 if (isDrawing) {
 ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
 ctx.stroke();
 }
 };
 el.onmouseup = function() {
 isDrawing = false;
 };

 }

 // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

 // set canvasImg image src to dataURL
 // so it can be saved as an image
  document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

here is the output::

[image]

this is static plan ,

And i want to create dynamically and store the complete plan on my database(MySQL) it is possible? give sufficient answer.

Comment: The approach I would go for would be to create a separate logical map object, where you keep information about coordinates and dimensions and based on that object you draw on the canvas. You can also save this object into the database easily as it is only data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic approach todo this is called **MVC-Pattern** (ModelViewController-Pattern) where you seperate the painting-logic from the model which keeps the data that describes what should be painted. 
It also seperates the controlling-logic from the painting-logic.

Try to find an object-oriented way to describe your floorplan by ignoring how the plan will be painted. You could do that by -for instance- creating a Floor-Object and a Room-Object. A Floor-Object would contain Room-Objects.
Each Room-Object would know where it is on the Floor and how it is formed or what size it has.

That model can easy be saved in a DB.

You would then write the painting-logic in a way that the logic knows how to paint the model on the canvas.

For more Informations on MVC see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having here shows that there is some missing layer(s) of abstraction in your application.

First thing is you need to define a proper board object. It will have properties such as it size, a somehow organized collection of the plan part, and most likely you'll need some others i cannot guess.

You need also a plan part object, -i can't guess what would be a good name- which seems to be only rectangles on your example.

Once you have those two object, it's pretty much straightforward to 'serialize' them to a DB, with a sql table having a list of boards, and another table having a list of 'floor parts' linked to their own board through an identifier.

I just made small classes to get you started, fiddle is here :

http://jsfiddle.net/48gnjwae/1/

As of now, it does the same thing as your code, but it will be way easier to save/restore things from that point.

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------

 function Board(gridWidth, gridHeight, graphicSize) {
     this.gridWidth = gridWidth;
     this.gridHeight = gridHeight;
     this.graphicSize = graphicSize;
     this.planParts = [];
     // no need to serialize this property 
     // but you have to rebuild it after loading from DB
     this.grid = new Array(gridWidth * gridHeight)
 }

 Board.prototype = {
     draw: function (ctx) {
         this.drawGrid(ctx);
         for (var i = 0; i < this.planParts.length; i++) {
             this.planParts[i].draw(ctx);
         }
     },
     canAdd: function (part) {
         // uses getGrid to check no cell is already covered
         // for (x) { for (y) { if this.getGrid(x,y) return false}}
         // return true;
     },
     addPart: function (part) {
         this.planParts.push(part);
         // + setGrid for all covered cells
         // for (x) { for (y) { this.setGrid(x,y,true)}}
     },
     getGrid: function (x, y) {
         return this.grid[x + y * this.gridWidth];
     },
     setGrid: function (x, y, val) {
         this.grid[x + y * this.gridWidth] = val;
     },
     drawGrid: function (ctx) {
         ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
         ctx.save();
         ctx.scale(this.graphicSize, this.graphicSize);
         ctx.lineWidth = 1 / this.graphicSize;
         for (var x = 0; x <= this.gridWidth; x++) {
             line(ctx, x, 0, x, this.gridHeight);
         }
         for (var y = 0; y <= this.gridHeight; y++) {
             line(ctx, 0, y, this.gridWidth, y);
         }
         ctx.restore();
     }
 }
```

Now the part :

```
 // ----------------------------------------------------------

 function PlanPart(board, x, y, w, h) {
     this.board = board;
     this.x = x;
     this.y = y;
     this.w = w;
     this.h = h;
 }

 PlanPart.prototype = {
     draw: function (ctx) {
         ctx.save();
         ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
         ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
         ctx.scale(this.board.graphicSize, this.board.graphicSize);
         ctx.lineWidth = 2 / this.board.graphicSize;
         ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
         ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
         ctx.restore();
     }
 }
```

In use :

```
 // ----------------------------------------------------------

 var myBoard = new Board(8, 8, 50);

 var part;
 part = new PlanPart(myBoard, 0, 0, 2, 3);
 myBoard.addPart(part);
 part = new PlanPart(myBoard, 3, 3, 2, 3);
 myBoard.addPart(part);
 part = new PlanPart(myBoard, 5, 3, 2, 3);
 myBoard.addPart(part);

 myBoard.draw(context);
```