# Best approach for (drawing and) storing a floorplan?

Tags: html, canvas

I've a project coming up which needs a basic floor plan for an exhibition to be stored in a database.

I'm thinking I'll use HTML5's Canvas and write code for a basic drawing tool for the client (I can't see any libraries specifically the help with this) but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255079/how-can-i-store-floor-plan-dynamically) has been helpful.

I'll be passing the data back to php via jquery (probably using a bit localstorage to speed things up).

My Question: Should I store the 'instructions' for recreating the floorplan as canvas drawing instructions or would I be best to go with the idea of a large grid with each cell of the grid being assigned a different role (corridor, exhibition stand, fire exit)?

Or is my whole approach wrong?

Comment: My 2-cents based on my lack of experience (grin): exhibition floorspace seem to fall into just a few sizes of individual sellable areas. If your eventual layout will be only a dozen different sized  areas, then create a JS template that renders each of the dozen types of areas to the canvas. Then your data is reduced to x, y, orientationRotation, templateType plus the info about who is assigned to that space.

Comment: What's up with everyone doing floorplans/layouts recently? BTW, asking for "Best" is often a death sentence for your question on Stackoverflow. They don't like questions that involve subjective answers here ;=)

Comment: @markE I see there are questions coming by the bunch from time to time. I suspect they are due to school/course assignments and the school was foolish enough to give them internet access :) (disclaimer: not saying this post is).

Comment: @markE Thanks for the advise. I'll update this when I've had a wee play. Good to know I'm going down the right path.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Client work for me ;) I wish I had project like this back in my School days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO -

Store shape definitions, not instructions. Define shapes depending on your needs, perhaps you need a circle shape, a rectangle shape, a polygon shape and so forth. Define them as objects. Have a tool for each shape. Add properties to the objects such as colors, line thickness etc.

```
function Rectangle(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

(literals are fine too).

Store the shapes in an array. If you want to support layers use sub-arrays (or 2-dimensional arrays) for that.

```
var r1 = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
var r2 = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
var shapes = [r1, r2]; // shapes.push(r1, r2);
```

If your objects are simple (ie. not embedding methods/functions) you can serialize them and send them as JSON to server and back without changing them (or for example use LocalStorage as a temporary storage between sessions). Using vectors allow you to scale your drawings to any size as well as export/import your data to CAD software later.

```
// to server
var json = JSON.stringify(shapes);

// from server
shapes = JSON.parse(dataFromServer);
redrawShapes();  // something to render the shapes
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. So, I think you are suggesting using shapes with co-ordinates, rather than a huge grid. That would work :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something similar to what we did for the TelerikNEXT conference - https://www.nativescript.org/blog/add-floor-plans-in-your-nativescript-application-with-officernd-api